# Class level locks - good or bad?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, concurrency, multiprocessing

I have a class, that takes a socket connection as an argument in its constructor. Writing and reading with that connection executed in threads. Repeated calls of asynchronous socket operations can cause data corruption and I need to do them thread-safe.

Why I need class-level lock? Because a connection can be shared between instances of the class.

Straight-forward solution here is to have `Lock` instance as a class attribute, but It kind of questionable.
Is it good design decision? Does somebody know better solutions?

Comment: Lock up at class level?  Why?  Could you not have more than one instance of this class with different connections?  Even a lock on an instance seems to me to be inappropriate if the class is a subsystem and can operate asynchronously with it's internal threads.

Comment: @MartinJames This class is public part of a library, so I cant predict, how it will be used, so I need to make solid design with minimum oddities and confusion from library-user point of view. Regarding internal threads - I think, that it is generally better to use global thread pool than internal threads - because its more elegant and you can set maximum number of threads for whole system (if you have counter-arguments, I would appreciate if you express them).

Comment: You use one lock per ressource. one lock per socket. store it like this: `sock.my_lock = Lock()`